# Directories not writable

Tags: directory

After installing civicrm in wordpress i have this error, see screen cap,
All my directories ../plugins/civicrm and ../uploads/civicrm have all permissions.
And when i click on details, i have no response.
[image]
I have forgotten a directory ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the problem, disk space exceeded on server. That is the reason it could not write.